# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read' Video Record + python selenium

Tags: python, opencv

I'm new to Python. My TL gives me a project that automates screenshot and video recording. I already manage to create and successfully run the screenshot, however, in video recording I encountered this error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'` and I already searched in google but I can't find an answer or how to do it. Anyone can help me with this problem?

Below is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0).release()
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG")
rec = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc,1,(640,480))


while True:
    b, img = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow("Screen Record",img)
    rec.write(img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)&0xFF
    if key == ord('q'):
        rec.release()
        break
cam.release()
cam.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You immediately release the video capture after creating it. Therefore, when you attempt to read from it, you get an error. Remove the release in the intialisation of your video capture and try again. You can also check whether the capture was opened sucessfully, using cam.isOpened():

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG")
rec = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc,1,(640,480))

while(cam.isOpened()):  // evaluates to True if your capture was opened successfully
   // do stuff!
```